# How to receive session id from json string coming from android client and compare the session id in java

Tags: android, session, session-cookies, persistent-storage

I have created an restful service which allocates the session id to the android client after successful login and from server side we send that session id in json string now when the android client again sends that same session id I don't know how to check for that old session id because when client send that same session id here at java side application is creating new session id..
please help me about how to receive that session id from json string and check at server side..

any help from android client side would also be appreciated ...if they are doing mistake

Comment: What do you have at server side? Servet or jsp or something else?

Comment: we are having restful service in server side

Comment: and how is this an android problem ? as you explained your server side makes the new session.

Comment: and I am just guessing you want to make that client(android) if its already has the session id then it should logged in automatically or something no ?

Comment: i got the problem ...any way thanks for your precious reply...